# Sharing config/dot files as a package?

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json

In the npm ecosystem it is becoming a common practice to configure various libraries using either dotfiles, package.json entries, or `*.config.js` files.

In order to establish common practices across different projects in our organization, I would like to be able to provide defaults for these configs (eslint, babel, vue, npmrc, editorconfig, jest.config, postcss.config, etc?) as a package that can be installed using npm and affect projects using it.

I can't just add those files in a dependency, but I could write a command to copy a group of files to the root of a repository. I'm wondering if there are standard/accepted ways of approaching this problem.

Comment: no there is not yet

Comment: if your team is using vscode, you can sync all your settings to a github gist. https://mikefrobbins.com/2019/03/21/backup-and-synchronize-vscode-settings-with-a-github-gist/